# How to find out number of real solutions to this without graphing?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$
3^x = 4x^2
$$

My prof's notes just says to look at the graph and you'll see that they intersect in 3 points. But is there another way of doing this if you can't graph it?

Comment: You could define a function $f(x)=3^x-4x^2$ and look for zeros if you've worked any with finding zeros.

Comment: You can say that there are at most 3 solutions, see
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/646092/number-of-solutions-of-px-eax-if-p-is-a-polynomial

Comment: By inspection, you could easily locate three roots since, if $f(x)=3^x-4 x^2$, you have $f(-1)=-11/3$,$f(0)=1$,$f(1)=-1$,$f(2)=-7$,$f(3)=-9$,$f(4)=17$.

Comment: @Claude; for those of us who are lazy, the $x$ values to look at are "large negative", $0$, $1$ and "large positive", giving $f(x)$ as "larger negative", $1-0=1$, $3-4=-1$, and "even larger positive"

Answer (score 1):

The Intermediate Value Theorem migh be usefull here.
Let $f(x) = 3^x - 4x^2$. 
Then $f(-1) <0$, $f(0) >0$, $f(1)<0$ and $f(4)>0$

As $f$ is continuous, there is at least one root in ]-1,0[, one root in ]0,1[ and one root in ]1,4[

Answer (score 0):

Mathematica

```
Solve[3^x == 4 x^2, x]
```

There are no analytic solutions.

Comment: There are analytic solutions using Lambert function as for any equation which can write $A+Bx+C\log(Dx+E)=0$. in principle, any CAS provides the three solutions.