# Number of real solution of $e^x=x^n\;,$ where $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: calculus

> Number of real solution of $e^x=x^n\;,$ Where $n\in \mathbb{N}$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ If $n=1\;,$ Then we get $e^x=x$

Now Let $f(x)=e^x-x\;,$ Then $f'(x) = e^x-1\;,$ and $f''(x)=e^x>0\;\forall\;  x\in \mathbb{N}$

So $f''(x)=0$ has no real Roots, Then Using $\bf{LMVT}$, We get $f'(x)=0$ has at most one real roots

And $f(x)=0$ has at most $2$ real roots.

But Using Wolframalpha, We get no real roots.(I did not understand how can i calculate it.)

Now Put $n=2\;,$ We get $e^x=x^2$

Now let $f(x)=e^x-x^2\;,$ Then $f'(x)=e^x-2x$ and $f''(x)=e^x-2$ and $f'''(x)=e^x>0\;\forall\; x\in \mathbb{R}$

So $f'''(x)=0$ has no real roots And again Using $\bf{LMVT}\;,$ We get $f''(x)=0$

has at most one real roots and $f'(x)=0$ has at most $2$ real roots and $f(x)=0$

has at most $3$ real roots

Now Here $f(x)=e^x-x^2$ has one root $x\in (0,1)$ Now i did not understand How can I calculate

In which interval other roots Lie

And How can I calculate no. of real Roots of $e^x=x^n$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Help required, Thanks

Comment: Note that for n=1, there is no intersection between the graph of $e^x$ and that of the first bisector

Comment: This may help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/646092/number-of-solutions-of-px-eax-if-p-is-a-polynomial

Comment: For even $n\gt e$ you might reasonably expect three solutions, one negative and two positive.  For odd $n\gt e$ you might reasonably expect two solutions, both positive.

Comment: Consider the function (e^x)/(x^n) : its derivative, and for what x it is equal to 1 ?

Comment: Use the Lambert $W$ function to solve it in terms of $n$, which will then allow you to determine any real solutions (if any).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The derivate of $$f(x)=e^x-x^n$$

is $$f'(x)=e^x-nx^{n-1}$$

If $n$ is even, we have $f'(x)>0$ for all $x\le 0$, so there is at most one negative solution.

Because of $f(0)=1$ and $f(-1)=\frac{1}{e}-1<0$ for even $n$, there is exactly one negative root for even $n$.

If $n$ is odd, there is no negative root because of $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$

For positive $x$, we can use the equation $g(x)=x-n\cdot ln(x)=0$

The first derivate is $1-\frac{n}{x}$, the second derivate is $\frac{n}{x^2}$, hence always positive.

For $n=1$ and $n=2$, the minimum of $g(x)$ , which is at $x=n$, is positive, so there is no positive root. If $n\ge 3$, then $n-n\log(n)$ is negative, so there are two positive roots.